# Connect bot to dynamics 365 without hard coding the connection string; dynamically create the connection string from user input from the bot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm, botframework

I would like to create a bot using the Microsoft bot framework to ask a user for their login credentials like url, username and password. This would enable the user to connect to dynamics 365. I am assuming from the login credentials i can create connection string that would connect to dynamics 365 by storing the credentials in cosmos db and from the credentials create the connection string from there but i am unsure if this is the right way to connect to dynamics 365 via the bot. I see examples were you hard code the credentials in the bot app to dynamics 365 but i want the user to enter credentials in order to connect to dynamics 365. If you can point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One excellent approach for handling 3rd party app authentication to D365 Online is to use the multi-tenant [Server to Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/build-web-applications-server-server-s2s-authentication) (S2S) approach. This basically secures your app with Microsoft's own Auth dialogs. Once the user authenticates, you're bot will receive a bearer token that will permit it to access D365 as the user.

The first time a user logs in, they have to consent to letting your app access D365 as them, then you're off to the races. The downside is that this will work only for D365 Online instances.

For IFD/ADFS instances, you could fall back to prompting for credentials. You might want to consider not storing the credentials long term in favor of using them only for the session, and then discarding them.

If you do want to get into the business of storing credentials long-term (which to me is a dicey business), you should probably look into [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/), or if you're going to store them in Cosmos, at least encrypt/decrypt them on the fly (and perhaps store your private key in Azure Key Vault).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Bot Service provides an OAuth connection service, and will manage tokens for you.  Dynamics CRM is one of the options.

[image]

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication